# Locale specific formatter for units after a number

Tags: java, locale, formatter

Is there a way to localize a number and unit like 1,234.56GB using a locale-specific formatter?

There are languages in which there should be a space between the number and the unit, such as Norwegian and Finnish (in addition to the difference in the formatting of the number itself).

Expected Result:

Norwegian - 1 234,56 GB (There should be a space before GB)
English - 1,234.56GB

My code:

```
        double val = 1234.1744689941406;
        String mb = "MB";

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("no"));
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
        df.applyPattern("###,###.##");
        df.setPositiveSuffix("MB");
        String output = df.format(val);
```

But this is giving me a result of 1 234,56GB.

Comment: Have looked at [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)?

Comment: Is that gigabytes? Are you following some standard? Do you have a reference?

Comment: So you are saying there should be a space *before the positive suffix*?

Comment: @RealSkeptic He's saying that there should be a space between `1` and `2` at the start of the text

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't think so, as he specifically shows that his code gives that space as output.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Point :P

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes there should be a space before positive suffix only for some languages like norwegian and finnish.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if there are also other languages that needs a space before the positive suffix(MB) i am only sure about norwegian and finnish so i really cant use a condition for 2 different format(with space and without a space) so i want to rely on a locale-specific formatter. Since im not that knowledgeable in Java i want to ask if a locale-specific formatter for this type of unit is possible. :)

Comment: @Pseudonymous is this possibly relavent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670337/need-space-between-currency-symbol-and-amount

Comment: I knew I recently read something very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41548046/982149

Comment: Only problem in above answer is: You have to create resource bundles, so the knowledge if there shall be space between value and suffix has to be privided by *you*.

Comment: @Fildor i am actually asking for an alternative way aside from using resource bundle. If and only if there really is an alternative way because some might know. Like for date and percentage we have a locale-specific Java formatter that we could use. But how about others like temperature and unit sizes.